# how to write error back to browser in koa

Tags: node.js, koa

I am new to koa, and using it as my app server.

My goal is to find an easy way to tell client the detailed errors, but with the recommended statements: this.throw(500, 'validation failed', {user: 'it is required'}), the client only get 500 with content as 'Internal Server Error', however my expectation is send client with 500 with content as {"user": "it is required"}. Did I miss anything or how to achieve my goal?

Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 1):

The browser simply expects things differently than Node.

`500` is an HTTP status. One sends this back in `Koa` as `this.status = 500;`. You seemed to not be okay with that, however that is the proper way to do it. If you are looking for something more specific, there are a ton of HTTP statuses in the `500` range, which all refer to server-end errors. [Here's a list of all HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

On the content, you would send it in `this.body`, and this is the body of content returned to the browser. You can send a JSON object back, with your own custom message if you would like.

```
this.body = { 
  error: true, 
  message: "Validation failed.", 
  user: "it is required" 
}
```

#### Edit:

You should send back a `401` unauthorized status, which is the standard status code for this scenario.

Comment: I understand the state code, what I want is the content. I want notify the client not only the state code but also the detailed error message.

Comment: Gotcha. Was still typing. check it out now.

Comment: But how to combine the detailed error message with this.throw statements?

Comment: You don't "throw" an error to the browser. You can make an event handler "catch" your throw, but that isn't necessarily the right way to do it.

Comment: I tried to write detailed error in error handler by with no luck like below: app.on('error', function(err, ctx) {
 ctx.body='user error';
})